# Bounded subharmonic function in the complement of unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose $H$ is subharmonic function in the $\bar{\mathbb{D}}^c$ (i.e., the complement of the unit disc in the complex plane) which is bounded (both above and below) and continuous up to the boundary. Can $H$ be non-constant? If it is possible, it will be good to have an example.

Comment: Consider $u(1/z),$ where $u$ is harmonic in the disc.